Why can't I use "type(num) != int" in a class method in Python?
I'm making a simple Bank Account class in Python. I was trying to make sure the input of set_balance() is either an int or a float. The balance is equal to 0 by default. The code goes as follows:
def set_balance(self, balance):
        if type(balance) != int or type(balance) != float:
            return

        if balance < 0 or balance >= 100000:
            return

        self._balance = balance

However whenever I set the balance then print get_balance(), the result is 0.
I even broke the or statement into two if statements as follows:
def set_balance(self, balance):
        if type(balance) != int:
            return
        
        if type(balance) != float:
            return

        if balance < 0 or balance >= 100000:
            return

        self._balance = balance

For some reason, type(balance) != int and type(balance) != float will not work in the class method.
I was able to get the desired results with the following code:
def set_balance(self, balance):
        if type(balance) not in [int, float]:
            return

        if balance < 0 or balance >= 100000:
            return

        self._balance = balance

I have used code like while type(num) != int: in a different piece of code and it worked just as expected. Is there a reason why this type of code doesn't work in a class method?

Think about what or vs and does. Typical rookie error, but you did a good job asking the question with complete information, hence the upvote.

Also, don't do this. What if someone passes in a Decimal or a numpy scalar that quack just like a number of dollars but aren't int or float?

@MadPhysicist I improved the question. but my qustion was not answered. The question was not about the or condition. My question is why type(balance) != num does not work in a class method?

type(balance) != num is working just fine. You are just not understanding what or does. this is a basic logical error, it happens pretty frequently, but think hard about what or means and your conditions. Thinks about what ahppens when balance = 10, then what should happen here and why:type(balance) != int or type(balance) != float .... that condition will be true

@mkrieger1 When I run the code with type(balance) != num to print get_balance(), I get the default value which is zero. But when I changed the code to say if type(balance) not in [int, float], the code worked as expected. In a different piece of code unrelated to this one, I did a while loop that started as while type(num) != int: and it worked then. But it wasn't in a class method.

If you split it into two operations, type(balance) != int and type(balance) != float, one or the other (if not both) will be true, so you'll always return. If your type is int, type(balance) != float will be true so you bail there. If your type is float, type(balance) != int will be true, so you bail there.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I broke the or statement up into two if statements: if type(balance) != int: and if type(balance) != float:. I still get the default balance of 0 no matter what I set the balance to.

So the guidance to think about what or means was completely relevant to your problem. One or the other condition will always be true (since a single value can't be both an int and a float), so when you combine them with or or an equivalent sequence of distinct conditions, you're effectively saying if True: return

Using "[...]" as the placeholder for your type(balance): What will happen when you have an int and check if [int] != int or [int] != float. It's true, because [int] != float. The other way around [float] will also trigger [float] != int. In both cases you return, even though you don't want to return. The same issue happens with the individual checks. One passes, the other does not. Your type(balance) can not be both int and float at once. You don't want or. You want and.

This isn't just about checking types, by the way -- people make the same mistake comparing strings &c all the time; it's a generic new-to-thinking-about-boolean-logic issue.

maybe first check print( type(balance) )

@furas, eh, they'll totally have this problem even if type(balance) == int or type(balance) == float, so I don't see what the point of that check would be. (Indeed, we know it's actually one of those two, because their corrected code fixes the issue).

I understand now. I needed to use and here, not or because the statement would reject both float and int which is not what I want it to do. Thanks everyone.

Glad you were able to work through it
